# ListView disappears Android Studio

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio

First of all, I am a beginner in java :)
My project is to create a todolist. Everything is finished but here I have a little problem. I searched on the internet but all the solutions I found did not do anything.

My app is divided into 3 fragments: my section "Add task", my section "To Do" and my section "Done".

In "To Do" and "Done" I have 2 respective listviews .
My problem is that when I go in the "Done" section I have my objects in it, but when I change the section to go back to "Add Task" and then go back to "Done", here is no more nothing .. my listView no longer appears.
On the other hand concerning the list "To do" no worries!

I really have trouble understanding what's going on .. I leave you some code so you can help me thank you in advance!

[My Done Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDvvL.png) -> Click on "Add Task" -> [My add section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xi7Pt.png) -> Then Go back to "Done" -> [Re- Done Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt6N6.png)

My DoneController :

```
public class DoneController extends Fragment {

private static ListView lv;
private static ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
private static View rootView;
public static Handler handler = new Handler();


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.done, container, false);
    lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_done);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    handler.post(runnableCode);
}

public static Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        addTaskDone();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
    public static void addTaskDone(/*String txt*/) {

    TaskDbHelper mHelper = addTaskController.getHelper();
    ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.query(TaskContract.TaskDone.TABLE_DONE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.TaskDone._ID, TaskContract.TaskDone.COL_TASK_DONE_TITLE},
            null, null, null, null, null);
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskDone.COL_TASK_DONE_TITLE); taskList.add(cursor.getString(idx));
    }
    if (mAdapter == null) {
       mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(rootView.getContext(), R.layout.done, R.id.task_title2, taskList);
       lv.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(taskList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}
```

}

NB : My ToDoController who does not have a problem with the display :

```
public class TodoController extends  Fragment {

public static Handler handler = new Handler();
private static ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;
private static ListView mTaskListView;
public static View rootView;
public static Boolean isInit = false;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo, container, false);
   mTaskListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_todo);
    rootView.setClickable(true);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Button bttn_del = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.task_delete);
    Button bttn_edit = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.task_edit);

    bttn_edit.setVisibility(rootView.INVISIBLE);
    bttn_del.setVisibility(rootView.INVISIBLE);

    handler.post(runnableCode);


    mTaskListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Object o = mTaskListView.getItemAtPosition(i);
        }
    });

}

public static Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateUI();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};

public static void updateUI() {
    TaskDbHelper mHelper = addTaskController.getHelper();
    ArrayList<String> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = mHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE,
            new String[]{TaskContract.TaskEntry._ID, TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE},
            null, null, null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE);
        taskList.add(cursor.getString(idx));
    }

    if (mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(rootView.getContext(), R.layout.todo, R.id.task_title, taskList);

        mTaskListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    } else {
        mAdapter.clear();
        mAdapter.addAll(taskList);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Well if you're new I'd advise against `fragments` without properly exploring them first.

Comment: And because you are new I would like to point out that it is Java coding convention to capitalize class names. So `public class doneController` would be better written `public class DoneController`

Comment: You should put stuff like :  `lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.listview_done);` in the `onCreateView` method. No need to do this every time the Fragment resumes. And I suggest that you use `AsyncTask` instead of `Runnable` -- Easier for beginners to control

Comment: @Artemis I'll be careful what I start next time .. But my application works properly, there is just this problem of posting especially for the task Done: /

Comment: @Barns Ok it's fixed for the class name sry !
Yes my listview was init in onCreateView before, but with my multitude of tests I left it in onResume. Wherever it is it does not change my worries .. :/

Comment: Change your code from `Runnable` and implement the `AsyncTask`.  Do the main work in the `doInBackground` and use the results in `onPostExecute`. BTW. Capitalizing the class names helps you (and more importantly, your colleges) know what they are dealing with in your code.

Comment: I think you are using viewpager in activity. Therefore add this after you created your viewpager adapter: yourViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2); Hope that helps!